# como obtener el elemento de una lista en java y pasarlo a una variable?

Tags: java, jsf, loops

tengo el siguiente código, el cual manda a llamar un query que me regresa una lista,
dentro de esa lista hay un elemento que se llama getHoraEntrada, el cual viene en formato Date, y yo en mi vista solo quiero mostrar la hora, entonces lo que hice fue crear una variable String (horarioEntrada) y pasarle el valor, para despues obtener solo la hora con el codigo que viene abajo del if.

```
public void buscaDetalle() {


    incidenciaAnioMesDet = anioMesDetService.findIncidenciaAnioMesDeByAnioMes(cvePersona, annio, mes);
    for (IncidenciaAnioMesDet incidenciaDetalle : incidenciaAnioMesDet) {


        if (incidenciaDetalle.getHoraEntrada() != null) {
            horarioEntrada = incidenciaDetalle.getHoraEntrada().toString();
        }

        //Obtiene el formato correcto
        String str = new String(horarioEntrada);
        String time = str.split("\\s")[1].split("\\.")[0];
        entrada = time;

    }

}
```

Tengo la siguiente tabla donde muestro mis datos

```html
<p:dataTable id="table" var="detalle" styleClass="columns" style="max-width:3000px;max-height:770px;" rendered="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.muestraTablaDetalle}" value="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.incidenciaAnioMesDet}" emptyMessage="No se encontraron registros">

  <p:column headerText="FECHA" style="width:150px;" styleClass="columns">
    <h:outputText />
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="ENTRADA" style="width:150px;" styleClass="columns">
    <h:outputText value="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.entrada}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="SALIDA" style="width:150px;" styleClass="columns">
    <h:outputText value="#{detalle.horaSalida}" />
  </p:column>

  <p:column headerText="INCIDENCIA" style="width:330px;" styleClass="columns">
    <h:outputText value="#{detalle.incidencias.cveIdIncidencia} - #{detalle.incidencias.concepto}" />
  </p:column>

  <p:column headerText="ACCIONES" style="width:120px;text-align: center" styleClass="columns">
    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search" title="View" onclick="PF('modalIntentos').show();">

    </p:commandButton>
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

y en la columna de ENTRADA, muestro la hora que me arroja el query con la variable "entrada" que declare en mi metodo para mostrar solo la hora y lo hace

el detalle esta que el query me arroja un listado de registros y no todos los registros trae lleno el dato de hora entrada, entonces si yo no valido que sea diferente de nullo, truena mi pagina, pero si lo valido que sea diferente de null, asi como viene en mi metodo, en mi tabla me pinta todos los registros  con esa misma hora en el campo de ENTRADA, lo cual esta mal, xq no todos los registros trae lleno ese dato
como le puedo hacer para mostrar la hora en el formato que quiero, solamente en los registros que si traen ese dato??

Answer (score 1):

Deberias formatear la fecha en la vista, podrias usar:

```
<h:outputText value="#{detalle.horaEntrada}">
    <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="HH:mm:ss"/>
</h:outputText>
```

Comment: hola @Klaimmore  , ya lo intente agregar, pero me manda este error,  <f:convertDateTime> Parent not an instance of ValueHolder: org.primefaces.component.column.Column@46e0c9f4

Comment: Podrías agregar como lo dejaste en un edit de tu pregunta? Me parece que no editaste bien el h:outputText y lo dejaste como un tag auto cerrado

Comment: ya se puedo, era xq lo tenia asi  <h:outputText value="#{detalle.horaEntrada}"/> , gracias